# Find pairs with given difference

Tags: algorithm

Given n, k and n number of integers. How would you find the pairs of integers for which their difference is k?

There is a `n*log n` solution, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Please give me example.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

- Sort the array
- For each item `data[i]`, determine its two target pairs, i.e. `data[i]+k` and `data[i]-k`
- Run a binary search on the sorted array for these two targets; if found, add both `data[i]` and `data[targetPos]` to the output.

Sorting is done in `O(n*log n)`. Each of the `n` search steps take `2 * log n` time to look for the targets, for the overall time of `O(n*log n)`

Comment: Instead of n x binary search, you could just move through the sorted list with two pointers (s.t. `data[i] + k >= data[j]`) in `O(n)`. But of course, the sort will still dominate the overall complexity.

Comment: @mbschenkel therefore we shouldn't sort.

Comment: @Tacet Why not? The question specifically asks for an n*logn solution.

Comment: @G.Bach ok, maybe I should add, "if you want better complexity solution".

Answer (score 4):

For this problem exists the **linear** solution! Just ask yourself one question. If you have `a` what number should be in the array? Of course `a+k` or `a-k` (A special case: `k = 0`, required an alternative solution). So, what now?

- You are creating a hash-set (for example [unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) in C++11) with all values from the array. [**O(1)**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert) - [Average complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity) for each element, so it's **O(n)**.
- You are iterating through the array, and check for each element `Is present in the array (x+k) or (x-k)?`. You check it for each element, in set in **O(1)**, You check each element once, so it's **linear** (**O(n)**).
- If you found `x` with pair (`x+k`  /  `x-k`), it is what you are looking for.

So it's **linear** (**O(n)**). If you really want **O(n lg n)** you should use a set on tree, with checking `is_exist` in **(lg n)**, then you have **O(n lg n)** algorithm.

Apposition: No need to check `x+k` and `x-k`, just `x+k` is sufficient. Cause if `a` and `b` are good pair then:

```
if a < b then
 a + k == b
else 
 b + k == a
```

Improvement: If you know a range, you can guarantee linear complexity, by using bool table (`set_tab[i] == true`, when `i` is in table.).

Comment: For average case this could be fast (at the expense of double memory), but the worst case complexity of hast-table insert and lookup are O(n), so overall you risk ending up with `O(n*n)`. - Not use whether @gen wants worst or average case complexity.

Comment: @mbschenkel Right, but the chance for **O(n^n)** is negligible. Besides, if the range of numbers is known (and not too big) it's possible to guarantee linear complexity (bool array, for example). Or if the numbers are known in compile time, then you can choose a good hash function for this example.

Comment: This appears to take `O(n)` time to find **one** pair. I believe the OP was looking for a solution to find **all** of the pairs in `O(n*log n)`.

Comment: @beaker you can use this algorithm to find all pairs in **O(n)**. When you find a pair, push it on stack, or something. Just don't interrupt the function. That's all.

Comment: @Tacet Which would make the overall time complexity `O(n^2)`, correct?

Comment: @mbschenkel: That's technically correct, but probabilistically totally irrelevant. You can design a hash table with insert and lookup in `O(1)` [with high probability](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/With_high_probability), which is a much stronger guarantee. In particular, trying to find a sample that forces this algorithm into quadratic runtime is more naive than playing lotto.

Comment: @NiklasB. I completely agree, but this requires some care to be taken when dimensioning the hash-table. And since the question is specifically about complexity it must be mentioned.

Comment: @mbschenkel no, hash tables can dynamically manage their size with amortized constant overhead per operation

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I thought the best is n*log(n), that's why I mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Solution similar to one above:

1. Sort the array
2. set variables `i = 0; j = 1;`
3. check the difference between `array[i]` and `array[j]`
4. - if the difference is too small, increase `j`
   - if the difference is too big, increase `i`
   - if the difference is the one you're looking for, add it to results and increase `j`
5. repeat 3 and 4 until the end of array

Sorting is `O(n*lg n)`, the next step is, if I'm correct, `O(n)` (at most 2*n comparisons), so the whole algorithm is `O(n*lg n)`